# Check Token's Freeze Authority Existance

Tags: spl-token

I am trying to check if a token has a freeze authority via cli using it's mint address. Is there a document that contains this info?

Answer (score 2):

In the CLI, if you use the `display` subcommand, it will show the freeze authority:

```
$ spl-token create-token --enable-freeze
Creating token 2T8KrQHm1AoCviKaVo5mv49ixNuuJRn8Zj4it4TG4rHD under program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA

Address:  2T8KrQHm1AoCviKaVo5mv49ixNuuJRn8Zj4it4TG4rHD
Decimals:  9

Signature: 35zviZPAJALQXa4umocF35x2woFybN7JSdmnJ7uGfUbsWpjipQwAHykCx7ifr5GFv3hStWDjHcYSnb7FV52VisYs

$ spl-token display 2T8KrQHm1AoCviKaVo5mv49ixNuuJRn8Zj4it4TG4rHD

SPL Token Mint
  Address: 2T8KrQHm1AoCviKaVo5mv49ixNuuJRn8Zj4it4TG4rHD
  Program: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
  Supply: 0
  Decimals: 9
  Mint authority: 4SnSuUtJGKvk2GYpBwmEsWG53zTurVM8yXGsoiZQyMJn
  Freeze authority: 4SnSuUtJGKvk2GYpBwmEsWG53zTurVM8yXGsoiZQyMJn
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any resources on getting the freeze authority using the CLI. But you can use `getMint` from `@solana/spl-token` to get mint account data.

```
import { getMint } from "@solana/spl-token";

let mintAccount = await getMint(connection, mintAccountPublicKey);

console.log(mintAccount);
  /*
  {
    address: PublicKey {
      _bn: <BN: 7351e5e067cc7cfefef42e78915d3c513edbb8adeeab4d9092e814fe68c39fec>
    },
    mintAuthority: PublicKey {
      _bn: <BN: df30e6ca0981c1a677eed6f7cb46b2aa442ca9b7a10a10e494badea4b9b6944f>
    },
    supply: 0n,
    decimals: 8,
    isInitialized: true,
    freezeAuthority: PublicKey {
      _bn: <BN: df30e6ca0981c1a677eed6f7cb46b2aa442ca9b7a10a10e494badea4b9b6944f>
    }
  }
  */
```

`freezeAuthority` field is what you are looking for.